# Wordpress: using media gallery vs using ftp and file system for images

Tags: wordpress

We're setting up a WordPress site. Currently, it has approximately 50 images in its media gallery. I noticed when uploading WordPress seems to create multiple copies of the images in various sizes (small, medium, large). Most of those we aren't going to use.

So I got to wondering about just uploading the images elsewhere on our server and referencing them through a relative URL.

The one distinct advantage that would give us is we could easily control the folder structure around the images.

**What I was wondering if anyone can suggest *advantages and disadvantages* of using the file system and referencing the images through a relative URL directly vs from the Media Gallery?**

So instead of uploading and having WordPress store them in:

```
/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2016/07
```

we would reference them from our web folder:

```
/public_html/images/travel/
```

and

```
/public_html/images/interests/
```

and so on and so forth.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there would really be a disadvantage, other than regular users may not know how to upload images via FTP. Also, WordPress archives based on date, so it would be easier to locate the image for future use - however, if you want to just use a singular size and are happy to upload them yourself, I don't see why there would be an issue with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advantage:**

As you've mentioned, better structure and control over the images.

**Disadvantage:**

Some Wordpress core features may not work as intended. For example, the build-in gallery uses those resized images for thumbnails. Also, various plugin may also use them. It's not a big deal, if you are using completely customized WP.

**Possible Workaround:**
You can still use the "wp-content/uploads" folder without the ugly categorization by dates. Go to Settings > Media, un-check the following option "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders". New images that you upload through your Wordpress Media section will go directly to "wp-content/uploads". Take note that old images will not be affected by this option.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback. If I were to uncheck as you said, would I be able to 1) customize the folder path -> 2) create the new folder I want -> 3) upload images -> 4) delete custom folder path config specified in #1 -> 5) WordPress Gallery would work as intended? Then just rinse/repeat for each new custom folder I want? Seems like it should work.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can change "wp-content/uploads" it to any custom folder path, but you should stick with it. In addition, the option that I've suggested is not related to the folder path. It just removes the month/year categorization.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've marked it as the answer, but am still open if anyone else has other suggestions.